# changing / maintaining regions in magento

Tags: php, magento, region

does anyone know how you edit/maintain regions in magento - specifically adding ones for the uk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the Magento admin console, go to System->Configuration
2. Click on the "Manage Stores" link (In the upper left hand corner there's a section named "Current Configuration Scope".)
3. From here you should see all the configured websites, stores, and store views in the Magento system.  Explaining how all these related to one another is beyond the scope of any single StackOverflow article, but this [wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/magento-design-terminologies4) has the basics and this [wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/general/multiple-website-setup) may also be useful.
4. You'll need to setup either a seperate website or a seperate store or a seperate store view for your UK store, depending on your needs (sorry to be so vague)
5. Return to System->Configuration
6. Click on the Current Configuration Scope drop down

You should now see a nested view of all your configured websites, stores and store views.  Selecting "Default Config" will allow you to set config values for all stores.  Selecting a specific website, store or store view from this menu will allow you to set config values for a specific website, store or store view.  This will allow you to set specific config values for your UK store.

Answer (score 1):

Regions are stored inside 'directory_country_region' and 'directory_country_region_name' tables in database. Unfortunately there is no editor for them.
You can inspect Mage_Directory module and look at sql installation scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of extensions to manage regions. I recommend this one [Region Manager Plus](http://goo.gl/P463Yk)
That extension allows you to add, edit remove, and also have and incredible feature, now you can download regions from an API, in seconds just selecting the desired country.
And the most important, is free